# BlueSnap - How to make a transaction with product(pass data in custom field) using Hosted Payment Fields api? is jason format is okay?

Tags: bluesnap

I have created a product in the BlueSnap product catalog. Now I want to make a transaction under that specif product. I have also created a custom field in the product. Now how to pass the value in the custom field using hosted payment field API?

```
$transactionData = array(
    "pfToken" => $pfToken,
    "product" => array(
        "product-name" => "Product-name",
        "product-id" => 566291,
        "catalog-sku" => array(
            "contract-name" => "contract-name",
            "contract-id" => 2617873,
            "sku-custom-parameters" => array(
                "custom1" => "Custom value",
            ),
        ),
    ),
    "amount" => "08",
    "currency"=>"USD",
    "cardTransactionType"=> "AUTH_CAPTURE",
    "cardHolderInfo" => array (
        "firstName" => "first-name",
        "lastName" => "last-name",
        "zip" => "02451"
    )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a product id with the payment API. Maybe [this](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/metadata) feature can be useful to you instead? Otherwise, BlueSnap has a legacy API that allows you to use product-id and skus, contact their support to get the documentation for that.